# Run script when power button pressed

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, power-management, key-binding

When I push the power button, I want to run a script. For the sake of this scenario, say file.sh. So when I push the power button, I want to run file.sh and only file.sh.

Most of the solutions I found involved editing `/etc/acpi/powerbtn.sh`, but that file does not exist on my system. (I'm running Ubuntu 19.04) I tried creating it and populating it with the standard contents, but it didn't work. I also tried listening for key presses with `acpi_listen`, but nothing happened when I pushed keys, so I don't know if I just did it wrong or what. I tried using `xev`,which did pick up key events but nothing registered when I hit the power button.

Anyone know how to accomplish this, or what I am doing wrong?

P.S. I should mention, I would prefer a solution that can be done on the command line, ideally one without any 3rd party software. Thanks.

---

Similar question, but with no solutions:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/473693/run-a-script-when-power-button-is-pushed

Basically looking for the Linux equivalent of what they did here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12434863/executing-a-batch-script-on-windows-shutdown

---

EDIT: this is what I get from syslog:

`Feb  9 13:01:01 joe-Aspire-E5-576G gnome-session-binary[1624]: Entering running state`

And this is my file in events:

`event=button/power  action=/home/ragnvaldr/Desktop/test/sc.sh`
`

Answer (score 4):

Your question is answered in the **EXAMPLE** section of `man acpid`. I will adapt to your needs.

- As a `root` create a file named `/etc/acpi/events/power` with contents like this:

```
event=button/power
action=/usr/bin/logger "ACPI_POWER_BTTN_TEST: %e"
```

- Then run `service acpid restart`.
- Tail the `syslog` file like this `/usr/bin/tail -f /var/log/syslog`
- Press the power button to see your test message in `syslog`.
- Change the `action=` line in the `power` file appropriately to point to your custom script.

### Troubleshooting:

1. After restarting `acpid`, check that `acpid` is actually running by using the `pidof acpid` command.
2. Does your script work as expected? Use full path names for commands in your script. Do *not* assume any value for `PATH`.
3. In the above example I used the the `/usr/bin/logger` command as an easy way to log something somewhere (`/var/log/syslog`). Alternatively, you can write something to a file under `/tmp` for testing purposes.
4. It has been reported (by @nathan) that some window managers may also capture the power button. It may help ensuring that `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` has the line `HandlePowerKey=ignore`, so that `systemd-logind.service` will ignore the power button.

Comment: I have tried this solution previously but it does not work. I get no feedback in syslog when pressing the power button on my machine.

Comment: I just edited the original post with the output from the terminal when I followed your solution.

Comment: Ok, so I got feadback working, but it wont run my script, this is my file: `event=button/power
action=/home/jeremiahgage/Desktop/test/sc.sh`

Comment: (1) Check that `acpid` is running with `pidof acpid`. (2) Does your script logs something to a file? I had user `logger` command as an **easy** way to log something somewhere (`syslog`). But, you can write something to a file in `/tmp` for example...

Answer (score -1):

> Basically looking for the Linux equivalent of what they did here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12434863/executing-a-batch-script-on-windows-shutdown

If this is what you want to do, then you can run scripts when the system shuts down (or is hibernated or put to sleep) using the [`systemd` infrastructure](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/39226/how-to-run-a-script-with-systemd-right-before-shutdown).

Comment: I dont want the system to shut down tho, just run the script.