# Issue with an ACPID bash script

Tags: linux, bash, keyboard, power-supply

My last post didn't get a correct answer, so I decided to refine/narrow my question in another post. If you want to refer to the other question, go:

[Run script when power button pressed](https://superuser.com/questions/1523918/run-script-when-power-button-pressed)

So I am trying to execute a bash file upon power key press. According to the documentation for ACPID, I created a file named `power` with the following address: `/etc/apci/events/power`. In that file, I have the following script:

`event=button/power
action=/etc/acpi/script.sh`

So when I push the power key, `power` should be executed, which in turn fires `script.sh`, but nothing happens.

What am I doing wrong? (BTW, i'm running Ubuntu 19.04)

Comment: What does your script _do_? There's a big difference between "nothing happens because script doesn't get started" and "nothing happens because script's effects are invisible".

Comment: script.sh in this case is a test script. It is a simple script that creates a file on the desktop called file.txt . This is not the final script I will use, just to test the functionality.

Comment: Is the script executable and with a proper shebang? [This edit of yours](https://superuser.com/revisions/1524113/4) makes me suspect you *may* tend to run scripts by running Bash with an argument: `bash script.sh`. Even if `bash /etc/acpi/script.sh` succeeds, `/etc/acpi/script.sh` may not.